# Position absolute vs div height in a jQuery project

Tags: jquery

I have this project that assorted people have been helping me with here and I have a minor issue, if you see in my project here: http://jsfiddle.net/webmonkeycch/4JACw/3/ the red line indicates a footer div of a site and because the frame is being positioned absolute the red line jumps above. Now I understand that you cant measure the height of something positioned absolute and assuming that the content area will be changing height depending on the content so I was wondering if there is a better way or recreating the jquery project itself. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix would be to add `margin-top:24px;` to the .redBlock css

Comment: Cheers I may have forgotten a major point that the content area will change in height.

Answer (score 0):

try giving position:relative for cont2 classs.

http://jsfiddle.net/4JACw/8/.
hope this works.

Comment: Sorry I tried that, for some reason each of the "content" divs appears to be stacked on top of each other as they flow through, that's why I was thinking that the whole way the slider works needs a rethink, unfortunately I cant write jQuery but I did notice that each of the content divs just fades out to 0%, maybe they need to fade out and then become hidden? I tried float as well with no luck.